# How to secure with SSL HTTPS a Nginx front-end and Puma back-end in Amazon EC2 AWS

Tags: ssl, nginx, amazon-ec2, https, puma

I´m trying to migrate my website from http to https. The architecture is: An angularJS webapp front-end running on Nginx server (listening on port 80) that sends requests to a Rails API app running on a Puma server (listening on port 8080). Both servers are living together in an Amazon EC2 instance.

It´s my first migration to HTTPS and I´m not skilled at all. Reading a lot, I made some progress but now I´m stuck.

I would like to confirm if I´m in the right approach or however I´m in the wrong way.

At the moment:

1. I got a Let´s encrypt certificate, installed and updated  my Nginx server. Now, the server is listening in 443 and SSL in working in the front-end.
2. I thought that was enough to secure a site, but I realized I got a blocked:mixed-content error in the requests sent from the front to the back-end.
3. So, I assume I need to secure the backend also. (Please confirm)
4. Now (This is only working in development, not AWS instance) Trying to secure the backend Puma server I came to a quite easy approach: As the Rails API is private, I created a self-signed SSL certificate and just uses it to start the Puma server like this:

   bundle exec puma -b 'ssl://127.0.0.1:3000?key=puma.server.key&cert=puma.server.crt' -e development  -S ~/puma -C config/puma/development.rb

As said, this is working in development. My Nginx server is listening in 443 and sends requests to Puma listening in port 3000.

5. At this point, I tried to do the same in my EC2 production instance. But here, I got a wall where I´m stuck. I just created another self-signed certificate and started the puma server in the same way. But connections are refused. I understand the problem is the port 3000 in the EC2 security rules is not opened. I tried to open the port in both HTTPS, that EC2 didn´t allowed me because only works for port 443, and HTTP, but as server is started as SSL is not working neither.

So, at this point, I´m wondering if I´m in the right approach but I´m just missing something, or otherwise, this is a wrong approach for an EC2 instance and I need to do something really different. Note: I have read something about how to configure an Nginx server to proxy https, but at the moment, didn´t understand much. Should I go this way?

**Comments and questions after @ffeast answer:**

I understand your approach. It goes in the way of the second approach, I suggested. However, I have some questions:

1. Will I solve the blocked:mixed-content error that I get with this approach? Why? I mean, should the Rails API requests change? Note: At the moment, in Angular I have resources that sends requests like: //domain-name:8080/action and the Puma server is listening the requests in that port. I don´t have any proxy-pass at the moment.
2. I think you included de Nginx configuration connecting to the Puma socket, I guess I need to create this Puma socket, I will need to check how. If you know how would be helpful to include an example. If I configure Puma with this socket, do I need to startup Puma in an specific port?
3. I try to understand the whole picture, but I´m stil confused with:
   3.1 How the requests to the API (from Angular Nginx) should look like?
   3.2 If I should startup Puma in an specific port? I don´t know if it´s required with the socket approach...
   3.3 And how should the proxy-pass configuration looks like to match those requests.

Could you please clarify maybe updating your example? Let´s suppose at the moment the requests are like //domain-name:8080/action

**UPDATE**
I´m trying to config Ningx to proxy pass the requests to PUMA socket (in development at the moment). I´m getting errors, please see a new post to keep this clean: [Nginx proxy pass to Rails API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48027327/nginx-proxy-pass-to-rails-api)

**UPDATE 2**
It´s working! My website is secure with no errors! This is my configuration.

```
upstream api.development {
    # Path to Puma SOCK file, as defined previously
    server unix:/tmp/puma.sock fail_timeout=0;
}

server {
        listen       443 ssl;
        server_name  localhost;

        ssl_certificate      /keys/ssl/development.server.crt;
        ssl_certificate_key  /keys/ssl/development.server.key;

    #    ssl_session_cache    shared:SSL:1m;
    #    ssl_session_timeout  5m;

    #    ssl_ciphers  HIGH:!aNULL:!MD5;
    #    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers  on;

        location / {
            root   /path-to-app;
            index  index.html index.htm;
            try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html =404;
        }

        # Proxy pass requests to Yanpy API
        location /api {
           proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
           proxy_set_header Host $host;
           #proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto https;
           proxy_redirect off;
           rewrite ^/api(.*) /$1 break;
           proxy_pass http://api.development;
        }
    }
```

My only questions is: If I comment all proxy_set_header directives like this:

```
location /api {
               #proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
               #proxy_set_header Host $host;
               #proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto https;
               #proxy_redirect off;
               rewrite ^/api(.*) /$1 break;
               proxy_pass http://api.development;
            }
```

It works too. I understand they are not mandatory to work and should be included because they have some benefit?

Same with:

```
ssl_session_timeout  5m;
 ssl_protocols  SSLv2 SSLv3 TLSv1;
 ssl_ciphers  HIGH:!aNULL:!MD5;
 ssl_prefer_server_ciphers   on;
```

Comment: Please explain the `backend` vs. `frontend` terminology, as it's quite different from what I expect (normally, backend refers to server side code vs. frontend that refers to client side / browser code)... from what I understand you have two backend modules, one being the static file service (nginx) and the other a Ruby app?

Comment: Yes, the front-end refers to client side. It is an AngularJS app that sends requests to the Rails API where the business logic is. The front-end serves also the static files. Let me know if you need anymore details.

Comment: Amended my answer. In brief, 1 - you'll solve it if your js goes to the right endpoint. 2 - removed  unix socket, didn't expect it be confusing. 3* - see my answer

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You’re going a wrong way.

In most cases you don’t need to secure your backend app, here's why:

1. The traffic would go either via a local connection or an internal  network so it doesn’t make sense to route it over a secure connection
2. You’ll hamper nginx <-> backend communication performance (it's negligible but still)
3. You’ll get all sorts of issues with additional internal certificates
4. And even more - not all backend servers even support https processing - because it’s simply not their job
5. From development perspective, your backend web app shouldn’t care whether it’s running over http or httpS - these are environment issues that should be completely dissected from your app’s logic

So the task boils down to configuring https in nginx and doing [proxy_pass](https://nginx.ru/en/docs/http/ngx_http_proxy_module.html#proxy_pass) (https://nginx.ru/en/docs/http/ngx_http_proxy_module.html#proxy_pass) over an insecure connection to your HTTP-aware backend server.

The question is how to deal with the following:

1. web host name your backend server knows nothing about
2. whether to generate `http` or `https` urls
3. what’s the real client’s ip because your backend app would see nginx's ip address

Here’s how it’s usually solved:

1. `Host` header is passed via [proxy_set_header](https://nginx.ru/en/docs/http/ngx_http_proxy_module.html#proxy_set_header) and picked up by the backend server
2. `X-Forwarded-Proto` header is passed and usually respected by backend servers
3. `X-Forwarded-For` header contains the original user’s ip

I googled such setups related to `puma`, this is very close to how it might eventually look like (borrowed from here https://gist.github.com/rkjha/d898e225266f6bbe75d8),`@myapp_puma` section is of particular interest in your case:

```
upstream myapp_puma {
  server 127.0.0.1:8080 fail_timeout=0;
}
server {
 listen  443 default ssl;    
 server_name example.com;
 root /home/username/example.com/current/public;
 ssl on;
 ssl_certificate /home/username/.comodo_certs/example.com.crt;
 ssl_certificate_key /home/username/.comodo_certs/example.com.key;
 ssl_session_timeout  5m;
 ssl_protocols  SSLv2 SSLv3 TLSv1;
 ssl_ciphers  HIGH:!aNULL:!MD5;
 ssl_prefer_server_ciphers   on;

 try_files $uri/index.html $uri @myapp_puma;

 location @myapp_puma {
   proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
   proxy_set_header Host $host;
   proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto https;
   proxy_redirect off;
   proxy_pass http://myapp_puma;
 }

 error_page 500 502 503 504 /500.html;
 client_max_body_size 4G;
 keepalive_timeout 10;
}
```

Now about your angular app.
It needs to know what url it should use for the API requests.
It can be solved in numerous ways, but the main point is that NO URLS should be hard-coded in the code, you can use i.e environment variables instead. Here's one of the approaches [described](https://www.jvandemo.com/how-to-configure-your-angularjs-application-using-environment-variables/) - it uses an **env.js** file included before your angular app and then relies on the constants defined throughout the code. In your case apiUrl should point at the desired https endpoint

```
(function (window) {
  window.__env = window.__env || {};

  // API url
  window.__env.apiUrl = 'http://dev.your-api.com';

  // Base url
  window.__env.baseUrl = '/';

  // Whether or not to enable debug mode
  // Setting this to false will disable console output
  window.__env.enableDebug = true;
}(this));
```

Addition:
as your backend appears to be working on URLs without API prefix, 
you can use the following trick with nginx:

```
location /api/ {        
  ...
  proxy_pass http://api.development/;
  ...
}
```

notice a trailing slash after proxy_pass - in this case the location prefix will be removed. From [here](https://nginx.ru/en/docs/http/ngx_http_proxy_module.html#proxy_pass):

> If the proxy_pass directive is specified with a URI, then when a
>   request is passed to the server, the part of a normalized request URI
>   matching the location is replaced by a URI specified in the directive

Comment: I understand your approach. It goes in the way of the second approach, I said. However, I have some questions:

Comment: Well, you are right. Just didn´t mention I´m using constants in my URLs just to go to the point. My Angular requests are like //API_SERVER_URL/action where API_SERVER_URL is denfined somewhere as domain-name:8080

Comment: I have read about connecting to servers with unix sockets and looks like it´s a better approach that connections using ports. So, your socket configuration is welcome.

Comment: Okay. Just note that unix domain sockets are usable when nginx is placed on the same box where your backend app is working. So are all of your questions answered or anything else needs to be clarified?

Comment: I have created a new post with my config problems to keep this clean. Please see my update.

Comment: As it seems to be solved I'd suggest to delete it and move the resulting configuration into this topic

Comment: It´s working! See my update 2. I think you both guys helped me to solve the problem. Do you know if can I split the reward?

Comment: Unfortunately you can't https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/16065/how-does-the-bounty-system-work. As a workaround you can accept + upvote one of the answers and manually award the bounty to another answer

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like the whole ordeal is about the `blocked:mixed-content` error you're receiving somewhere:

- *Is it in the browser?*  For better or worse, browsers will never actually know whether the connections between your front-end servers and the back-end ones are over `http` or `https`.  In other words, it's more likely that the error is caused by something somewhere on your page still fetching content over `http`, whether from your own domain, or from a third-party one, not anything to do with the backend being proxied through the front-end server over `http`.  E.g., you might want to change those `src="http://cdn.example.org/….js"` to `src="//cdn.example.org/….js"` in your front-end code to make all your JavaScript scripts happy.
- *Is it on the backend?*  Generally, in order to "tell" the backend that the connection is secure, the front-end proxy must add an appropriate `X-Forwarded-Proto` header.

Otherwise, http://nginx.org/r/proxy_pass does support verified https in recent versions of nginx, and you can use a combination of `proxy_ssl_…` directives to configure the security policy, e.g., `proxy_ssl_trusted_certificate` with the public version of your self-signed certificate and/or CA, as well as `proxy_ssl_verify on;`.

---

P.S. Practically speaking, I disagree with the other answer on the merits of the performance impacts of encryption between the backend and front-end servers.  If you have reasons to believe that the connection may be evesdropped (and even Google discovered that their dedicated fibre lines between datacentres have been tapped upon by the governments), then, sure, do use self-signed `https` between the backend and front-end servers.
In terms of performance, the major cost of `https` comes from establishing the connection; but in the server scene, that one connection could then be reused for serving multiple clients (e.g., possibly controlled through `proxy_ssl_session_reuse`); and even if the connection cannot be reused, then the latency between the backend and frontend servers is generally small enough to be capable of sustaining a few extra roundtrips without performance impacts (especially considering that the latency towards the end-user is often on the order of magnitude larger than that).
With that said, the [`https` address scheme](http://lists.w3.org/Archives/Public/ietf-http-wg/2015JanMar/0106.html) nowadays is misused highly — most public sites have very little benefit of being put over mandatory `https`, as it'll simply reduce the number of folks that can access such sites (see [HTTP/2.0: The IETF Is Phoning It In](http://queue.acm.org/detail.cfm?id=2716278) for merely a list of policy-based issues, and there are also many technical issues of TLS incompatibility), plus client-facing `https` does reduce the performance due to requiring extra round trips for establishing the connections, so, if you don't get any extra benefits from `https`, it's often just a liability.  To summarise, your blog of occasional cat pictures might as well be better without it.

Comment: The blocked:mixed-content error is in the browser. I mean, I can check it in the resource tab of the browser Chrome inspector. You are right, at first I had the http:// in the requests inserted directly in the code, example: http://domain-name:8080/action. After reading about the error, I updated all my requests to relative  like //domain-name:8080/action. Then the protocol is automatically got. This is right but the point, is now the Puma API server does not listen the https requests.

Comment: @Rober, I think you're doing it wrong — there should probably be no mentions of `:8080` in your front-end javascript — you should implement proper proxying with nginx between the backend and front-end.  That's where your error is.

Comment: I´m not sure that I understood you. The other answer is proposing to proxy-pass to the server like you, right? What is the point you disagree with? It´s when it uses proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto https;  and you think this is not required?

Comment: @Rober If it's all running on the same machine, there's really no reason to use https.  Your port 8080 should be blocked from the outside, and you should use proxy_pass on the front-end to interface w/ the backend.

Comment: Ok. Let me try to make the proxy pass working and I will let you know if the whole problem is solved. Anyway, should I proxy pass to a port or better a socket? I´m reading about it, and looks like a socket is better.

Comment: I have created a new post with my config problems to keep this clean. Please see my update.

Comment: It´s working! See my update 2. I think you both guys helped me to solve the problem. Do you know if can I split the reward?

Comment: @Rober, glad it works; I don't think there's a way to split the bounty, but you could +1 both answers; I obviously would like my answer better as an accepted one for this question, for one, because it actually addresses the underlying `mixed-content` part of your question, which got completely overlooked by the earlier answerer, and is, basically, the root cause of the issues you've been having.

Comment: why is it overlooked? it's just a consequence and not a cause, that's why it hasn't been mentioned in the answer. In now way does it mean it has been overlooked